# Add a new column at the end of "|" (pipe) delimited file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a pipe delimited text file and I would like to add a new date column at the end of the each row of the file. I have about 100 rows in my file and so I would like to add current date column into my file for each of those rows. Text file also contains some null value as well.

Here is an example of the file:

```
Id|Num|Name
1 |24 |Sam
2 |3  |John
3 |   |James
```

Here is how file should look after date column is added

```
Id|Num|Name  |Date
1 |24 |Sam   |2018-01-25
2 |3  |John  |2018-01-25
3 |   |James |2018-01-25
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you include a "null value" into your sample?

Comment: I have updated the question with the example of a null query that is in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you could do it with `$sed` and `$column`

`sed  -e '1s/$/|Date/' -e "2,\$s/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/" -e 's/\>|/ |/g' file | column -t`

Output:

```
Id  |Num  |Name   |Date
1   |24   |Sam    |2018-01-26
2   |3    |John   |2018-01-26
3   |     |James  |2018-01-26
```

Explanations

- `1s/$/|Date/`: adds |Date to the end of the first line
- `2,$s/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/`: adds |(Today's date) at the end of every line from line 2
- `s/\>|/ |/g`: forces a whitespace before each | if not present
- `column -t`: formats the input in column

It won't work on mac unless you install gnu-sed and use `gsed` instead of `sed`

2. Following your comments, it seems your requirements are simpler than your original question, in which case you can execute the following commands:

   sed 's/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/' file

if the output suits you, you can then replace the file with the modifications

```
sed -ibak 's/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/' file
```

Explanations:

`-i means edit file in place and you can add an extension to get a backup (here bak)`

`s/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/'`

- `s` means I'm gonna make a substitution
- `/` is the separator
- `$` means end of line. So I'll replace the end of each line
- `|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`. Here is what I'm going to substitute the end of line with. $() is a command substitution, which means, it executes the command and uses the output of it to replace the end of the line

Comment: I wanted current date instead of hard-coded date. Also will this command save the output into the file or just print the output. Thanks for answering the question.

Comment: This will print the result to stdout. I guess you can redirect it to your file with >. To get the current date you can use the `date` command. I'll update my answer accordingly later today

Comment: I tried your updated command but it did not output the result into stdout and when I added > and the file name after column -t, nothing happended. File did not get updated

Comment: What os are you running on ? Can you try to add the sed statements one by one and we'll see which one is not working for you `sed '1s/$/|Date/' file` and we'll see if the Date is added, then the second part and so on

Comment: I am running this on Windows 7. I tried the latest command that you have posted here but it did not output any result nor when I added > and the same file name, it did not update the file as well.

Comment: Are you running it in cygwin ?

Comment: No. Through putty

Comment: I want to add the date to each line not every other line.

Comment: As I asked you, have you tried to run each part of the sed sequentially to see which one is failing for you. Have you looked a bit into the sed documentation?   This part of the sed `2,\$s/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/` means _add the current date to end of the line from line 2 to the end of the file_  What is the os you're logging on ?

Comment: The column headings provided in the example are not included in the file, so, the date column should be added into the file from line 1.

Comment: Do you also need the nice looking formatting with all columns aligned ?

Comment: I do not want nice formatting, but it should include date at the end of each row/line. I wanted to know why sometimes I get ^M when running sed command.

Comment: This is way more simple now. Just run `sed 's/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/' file`. If the output suits you, run `sed -ibak 's/$/|$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/' file` and it should add the date at the end of each line and save a copy of the file before transformation with the bak suffix.

Comment: You can take a look at https://its.ucsc.edu/unix-timeshare/tutorials/clean-ctrl-m.html about your question with the ^M

Comment: I was able to add the date with the line you provided, but I want to understand the reason behind why I am getting ^M and then the date is being added.

Comment: It is all about how your file is encoded. Windows and linux do not represent the end of line the same way. So if you move/edit/save your file from an operating system to another, you'll get this formatting issue. `dos2unix` or the sed command explained in the previous link I gave you should help you to solve this issue. For the rest, you should do some researches, as the questions you are asking are pretty basic and the answers for these are all over the internet